# Filter product with Ajax and return Json Array from a controller to show in a phtml file

Tags: magento2, product, ajax, filter

Is it possible to return an array from a controller or from a block function to the phtml file?

```
<?php

namespace Mnuhell\FormSearchAttributes\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Search extends Action
{

/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

protected $_resultJsonFactory;

protected $_coreRegistry;


public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, JsonFactory $_resultJsonFactory, Registry $_coreRegistry)
{
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_resultJsonFactory = $_resultJsonFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();

    $minPrice = $this->getRequest()->getParam('minPrice');
    $maxPrice = $this->getRequest()->getParam('maxPrice');
    $minQty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('minQty');
    $maxQty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('maxQty');
    //$category = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category');

    if($minPrice != "undefined" AND $maxPrice != "undefined" AND $minQty == "undefined" AND $maxQty == "undefined") {

        $sql = "SELECT cat.entity_id, cat1.value, count(prod.entity_id) AS totals FROM catalog_category_entity as cat 
            LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar as cat1 ON cat.entity_id = cat1.entity_id 
            INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as catprod ON catprod.category_id = cat.entity_id 
            INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as prod ON prod.entity_id = catprod.product_id 
            LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal as prec on prec.entity_id = prod.entity_id 
            LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock ON stock.product_id = prod.entity_id 
            where children_count > 0 and cat1.attribute_id = 45 and cat.entity_id > 2 
            AND prec.value > $minPrice and prec.value < $maxPrice 
            group by cat.entity_id ";


        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    }

    if($minPrice != "undefined" AND $maxPrice != "undefined" AND $minQty != "undefined" AND $maxQty != "undefined") {

        $sql = "SELECT cat.entity_id, cat1.value, count(prod.entity_id) AS totals FROM catalog_category_entity as cat 
            LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar as cat1 ON cat.entity_id = cat1.entity_id 
            INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as catprod ON catprod.category_id = cat.entity_id 
            INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as prod ON prod.entity_id = catprod.product_id 
            LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal as prec on prec.entity_id = prod.entity_id 
            LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock ON stock.product_id = prod.entity_id 
            where children_count > 0 and cat1.attribute_id = 45 and cat.entity_id > 2 
            AND prec.value > $minPrice AND prec.value < $maxPrice
            AND stock.qty > $minQty group by cat.entity_id";

            $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT cat.entity_id, cat1.value, count(prod.entity_id) AS totals FROM catalog_category_entity as cat 
            LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar as cat1 ON cat.entity_id = cat1.entity_id 
            INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as catprod ON catprod.category_id = cat.entity_id 
            INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as prod ON prod.entity_id = catprod.product_id 
            LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal as prec on prec.entity_id = prod.entity_id 
            LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock ON stock.product_id = prod.entity_id 
            where children_count > 0 and cat1.attribute_id = 45 and cat.entity_id > 2 group by cat.entity_id";

    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

     $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create($result); 

    $collection = $resultJson->setData($result);

    return $collection;

 }
}
```

How I can return **collection** array json in a phtml file?

Thanks!!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220376/how-i-get-ajax-response-from-controller-in-magento-2?answertab=active#tab-top